# Vectors making a plane and a third vector

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am helping my daugher with her math homework, and we are stuck on this question:

Suppose that `a` and `b` are nonzero vectors that are not parallel and `c` is any vector on the plane created by `a` and `b`.

We need a geometric argument that shows that `c` can be written as `c = sa + tb` where `s` and `t` are scalars.

We are supposed to then get an argument using components.

This is homework, so we are looking for an explaination over just a direct answer.

Comment: What precise definition does her class use for "the plane created by $a$ and $b$"?

Comment: @MW - It says "and `c` is any vector in the plane determined by `a` and `b`".

Comment: Right, I understand that, but generally speaking, one can define "the plane determined by $a$ and $b$" as the linear span of $a$ and $b$, meaning the set of all linear combinations of the form $sa+tb$.  So if she's using that definition, then it follows immediately from the definition.  That's why I thought maybe she was using a different definition in her class.

Comment: @MW - It is unclear what the definition is.  In her last class (linear-algebra) that was the definition.  But she just started her multivariable-calculus class and the teacher is not explaining things in a way that she is getting it.  So she is not quite sure if the definition is the same.

Comment: @Vaccano Can you look in her textbook for the definition of a plane? If not, can you ask her to refer to either her book or the class notes?

Comment: @JohnDouma We don't quite get it and can't seem to find it in the book.  As I understand it (and I am not very good at this stuff), any two vectors are going to make a plane.  Because these vectors are in two dimensional space, both non-parallel vectors make two "lines".  Any any two lines that are not three dimensional make a plane. (but I could be way off here)

Comment: I am not asking if you get it. I am asking you to print the definition given by the instructor. Multivariable calculus texts usually define a plane as the set of vectors whose dot product with a fixed vector is a constant. In your case, I suspect the plane is defined by $\vec v\cdot (\vec a\times\vec b)=k$ where $\vec v$ is a vector that lies in the plane.

Comment: @JohnDouma this is possible, however it seems a bit early in the semester for them to have hit the cross product, even for a quick vector geometry crash course.  It might be they want something more along the lines of an argument from plane geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not 100% clear what definitions you are starting from, here is a geometric argument that is hopefully along the lines of what you are looking for.

We will take as given the fact that if two vectors are taken from the same line, or parallel lines, then they are scalar multiples of each other, and the fact that for points $P$ $Q$ and $R$, we have $\vec{PQ}+\vec{QR}=\vec{PR}$.

Let $a=\vec{OA}$, $b=\vec{OB}$, where $O$ is the origin and $A$ and $B$ are points on the plane.  Then any vector on the plane spanned by these vectors can be written $c=\vec{OC}$.

If $c$ is a scalar multiple of either $a$ or $b$ then we are done (we can take the other coefficient to be $0$), so assume $c$ is not a scalar multiple of either of them. In particular, $C$ is not on either of the lines $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ or $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$.

Therefore, by the parallel postulate from Euclidean geometry, we can draw a line $L$ in the plane through $C$ parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$.  Since $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$ are not parallel, $L$ is not parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$, and therefore intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ at some point $D$.

Now we have $$c=\vec{OC}=\vec{OD}+\vec{DC}\text{,}$$
but since $D$ is on $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$, $$\vec{OD}=s\vec{OA}=sa$$ for some $s$, and since
$L$ is parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$, and $C$ and $D$ lie in $L$, $$\vec{DC}=t\vec{OB}=tb$$
for some $t$.

Comment: You are a math hero!!!  It makes sense and we are unstuck!  You rock!

Comment: Aww shucks :)  No problem, glad I could help!